# Generating vectors that will result in a HTML file with R results

Tags: html, r, write.table

I have already done this, so I know it's possible, and it might be a very simple issue, so I am sorry if the question is not good enough, but here is the deal:

I have a code in R to generate a few analysis from a stock: the log return, the histogram, a descriptive statistics from its value and the log returns, and so on.

What I want is to make a cool html with this results. I had something similar in my old job long time ago, but I am really struggling to remember exactly how I put the results into the html.

It starts with an empty object, then I add html codes and within the codes I start to insert my results. After that I use write.table and my work is done. Not sure why it is not working this time. I thought it could be something from the number of rows and columns some results have, but I couldn't solve the issue. This is what will generate the html:

```
HTMLGenerator<- ""
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<!DOCTYPE html>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<html>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<head>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<title>Stock Analysis</title>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("</head>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<body>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<h2>Stock Analysis</h2>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<h3>Stock: CSAN3</h3>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<h3>Made by me</h3>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("The Log Returns from CSAN3 are:\"",LogReturnCsan,"\" ",sep="" )
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste(" \"",DescriptiveStat,"\" ",sep="" )
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste(" \"",Histogram ,"\" ",sep="" )
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("</body>",sep="")
write.table(HTMLGenerator,"C:/Users/Desktop/FinalAnalysis.html",sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

And this is what the R code looks like:

```
#Read the stock information
Csan <- read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/csan.txt",header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)
#get the stock log return based on the close value from each day
LogReturnCsan <- diff(log(Csan$Close))
DescriptiveStat <- summary(LogReturnCsan)
#Makes a histogram with the log returbs
Histogram <- hist(LogReturnCsan, breaks=30, col="burlywood3", main="LN Return Csan3 ")
```

The HTML is failing to get the results from R such as the LogReturnCsan, DescriptiveStat and Histogram.

This is the content of csan.txt, each column is separated by "," and the decimals by "." (It is the Year, Day, Month, DayMonth, Open Value, Highest Value of the stock in the day, Lowest Value of the stock in the day, Close price in the day, Volume of tradings, Close Value adjusted):

```
Ano,Dia,Mes,DiaMes,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,AdjClose
2010,04,01,04 - 01,22.6185,22.7429,21.9964,22.6629,1088200,20.10939
2010,05,01,05 - 01,22.7696,23.0006,22.103,22.6718,2295300,20.11728
2010,06,01,06 - 01,22.503,22.7518,21.8364,22.023,2115500,19.54159
2010,07,01,07 - 01,21.7297,21.8186,20.3078,20.8499,8368700,18.50066
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without the contents of csan.txt. But in any case, this sort of problem is almost certainly better solved using RMarkdown and [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) rather than by the method you're currently using.

Comment: @NickK I've just added the information on csan.txt... I think knitr may help a lot, but this approach that I've used in the past looks so simple that I wanted to give a try

Comment: Your problem is that your treating LogReturnCsan, DescriptiveStat and Histogram as vectors of length 1, whereas LogReturnCsan has length 4, DescriptiveStat length 6 and Histogram is a list. What is your desired output?

Comment: @NickK you're right! I believed this was a problem. I've tried LogReturnCsan[1] and it works. However, I'm still struggling to build this HTML in a way that shows the results as I wanted to see (as a table for instance). Also, I'd have to make LogReturnCsan[2] and so on, up to the end. I still don't really know how to approach this. Perhaps some sort of loop and some tricks with the htmls code... not sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One inefficient way to do this:

```
#get the stock log return based on the close value from each day
LogReturnCsan <- data.frame(LogReturnCsan=diff(log(Csan$Close)))
DescriptiveStat <- summary(LogReturnCsan)
#Makes a histogram with the log returbs
Histogram <- hist(LogReturnCsan[,1], breaks=30, col="burlywood3", main="LN Return Csan3 ")

#If you want the Hist as table
Histogram$counts=c(NA,Histogram$counts)
Histogram$density=c(NA,Histogram$density)
Histogram$mids=c(NA,Histogram$mids)
Histtab=do.call(rbind,Histogram[1:4])

HTMLGenerator<- ""
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<!DOCTYPE html>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<html>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<head>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<title>Stock Analysis</title>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("</head>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<body>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<h2>Stock Analysis</h2>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<h3>Stock: CSAN3</h3>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<h3>Made by me</h3>",sep="")
write.table(HTMLGenerator,"FinalAnalysis.html",sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

library("xtable")
print(xtable(LogReturnCsan,caption = "Log Returns"), type="html",file="FinalAnalysis.html", append=TRUE)
print(xtable(DescriptiveStat,caption = "Descriptive Stats"), type="html",file="FinalAnalysis.html", append=TRUE)
print(xtable(Histtab,caption="Histogram Stats"), type="html",file="FinalAnalysis.html", append=TRUE)

endfile<-paste("</body>",sep="")
write.table(endfile,"FinalAnalysis.html",sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE,append = TRUE)
```

Comment: It was close to what I was looking for, not exactly, but it helps. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it using Rmd and `knitr::knit`. This file should be saved as (e.g.) Stocks.Rmd and then the following entered in R while in the same working directory as both this file and the data `knitr::knit("Stocks.Rmd")`. Alternatively, [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.com) has a great interface to `knitr`.

````
---
title: "Stocks analysis"
author: "by Me"
output: html_document
---

Stock: CSAN3
------------

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
#Read the stock information
Csan <- read.csv("csan.txt", fill = TRUE)
#get the stock log return based on the close value from each day
LogReturnCsan <- diff(log(Csan$Close))
DescriptiveStat <- summary(LogReturnCsan)
#Makes a histogram with the log returbs
```

The Log Returns from CSAN3 are:

```{r}
LogReturnCsan
DescriptiveStat
```
```{r echo=FALSE}
hist(LogReturnCsan, breaks=30, col="burlywood3")
```
````

If you want prettier formatting, you could use the `pander` library which can produce nicely formatted Markdown tables. You'll need to remember to set the chunk options for those tables to be `results="asis"` if you do use it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Just found an old code. It is not perfect yet, but now is a matter of adjusting the HTML part. The logic is ok:

```
#Read the stock information
Csan <- read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/csan.txt",header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)
#get the stock log return based on the close value from each day
LogReturnCsan <- c(1,diff(log(Csan$Close)))
DescriptiveStat <- summary(LogReturnCsan[-1])
#Makes a histogram with the log returbs
Histogram <- hist(LogReturnCsan[-1], breaks=30, col="burlywood3", main="LN Return Csan3 ")
HTMLGenerator<-""
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<!DOCTYPE html>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<html>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<head>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<title>Stock Analysis</title>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("</head>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<body>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<h2>Stock Analysis</h2>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<h3>Stock: CSAN3</h3>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("<h3>Made by me</h3>",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("The Log Returns from CSAN3 are:",sep="" )
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                         <left>  ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                             <table id='hor-minimalist-b-big'>       ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 <thead>     ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 </thead>        ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 <tbody>     ",sep="")
for (i in 1:length(LogReturnCsan)) {HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste(" ",LogReturnCsan[i]," ",sep="")} 
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 </tr>   ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 </tbody>        ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                             </table>        ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                         </left>     ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("The Descriptive Statistic for CSAN3 is:",sep="" )
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                         <left>  ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                             <table id='hor-minimalist-b-big'>       ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 <thead>     ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 </thead>        ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 <tbody>     ",sep="")
for (i in 1:length(DescriptiveStat)) {HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste(" ",DescriptiveStat[i]," ",sep="")} 
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 </tr>   ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                                 </tbody>        ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                             </table>        ",sep="")
HTMLGenerator[length(HTMLGenerator)+1]<-paste("                                         </left>     ",sep="")

write.table(HTMLGenerator,"C:/Users/Desktop/FinalAnalysis.html",sep="\t", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

Hope that will help someone who wants to make similar reports.

Cheers and thanks for the help!